# replacing underscore with hyphen in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change all the underscore in my url to hyphen, presently i am using the below code which is working fine, however i do not want to change the underscore in images link, i just want to change the links to page, is it possible ?

```
rewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ http://example.com/$1-$2-$3-$4 [R=301,L]
rewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ http://example.com/$1-$2-$3 [R=301,L]
rewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ http://example.com/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Untested code

Add the following statement at the very beginning of `RewriteRule`s block

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp)$ [NC]
```